# Running dropbox on linux

Tags: dropbox

So, I'd like to run the dropbox client on linux (gui preferred). I installed the .deb via dpkg and it tells me that I can go to my applications to menu to launch it. This doesn't actually help when I run a tiling window manager and don't have said menu. I seem to be able to manipulate it via CLI but still want to get the client running properly. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox doesn't have much of an interface; you'd only be launching a daemon that optionally shows up in the notification area (if you have one).

Just run `dropboxd` (or `dropbox`) from the command line and it will print an account-link URL. If you're running a notification tray program like `stalonetray` or `tint2`, Dropbox will appear there and will allow accessing the preferences window – but, really, that's the only graphical UI it has. If it syncs your files, it's running properly.

You can also download `http://linux.dropbox.com/packages/dropbox.py` as `~/bin/dropbox` to control the most common actions from command line.

---

(That said, the application menu is *not* a property of the window manager; there is nothing to prevent one from running something like `xfce4-panel` along with i3 or wmii, for example.)